# Hooks in Mongoose: What is 'this'

Tags: mongoose

I am new to Express and Mongoose. I was reading this [tutorial](http://scottksmith.com/blog/2014/05/29/beer-locker-building-a-restful-api-with-node-passport/)
Here is a snippet from the tutorial, where a `user` is being saved in the db.

```
// Execute before each user.save() call
UserSchema.pre('save', function(callback) {
  var user = this;

  // Break out if the password hasn't changed
  if (!user.isModified('password')) return callback();

  // Password changed so we need to hash it
  bcrypt.genSalt(5, function(err, salt) {
    if (err) return callback(err);

    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function(err, hash) {
      if (err) return callback(err);
      user.password = hash;
      callback();
    });
  });
});
```

1. What exactly is `this`. Does `this` means the new/modified document or `this` means the old one stored in the db? I suppose `this` is the new document. So is there any keyword to access the old document? At worst, I think, since this is pre save, I could access the old/saved doc, using `findOne`. Is there something better than this approach?
2. Here the author is checking if the password has changed or not. So I suppose `isModified`, compares the given field in the new document and old document and return a bool depending on modification or not. The problem is, while saving the author has saved a hash, but while checking for modification, I suppose he should first create the hash and then check if the hashes are same. Am I right, or am I missing something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - The `pre` hook gets called prior to saving the document in the database -- hence the word "pre". `this` refers to the document prior to saving. It will include any changes you made to its fields.

For example, if you did

```
user.password = 'newpassword';
user.save();
```

Then, the hook will be triggered right before inserting/updating the document in the database

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    console.log(this.password); // newpassword
    next(); // do the actual inserting/updating
});
```

2 - When editing a user, you could set the form's password input to be blank. Blank password input usually means no change is to be made. If a new value is entered, that is considered changing the password.

Then, you would alter your schema as below:

Add a [setter](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/getters-setters.html) for your password field

```
let UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    password: {
        type: String,
        // set the new password if it provided, otherwise use old password
        set: function (password) {
            return password || this.password;
        }
    }
    // etc
});

UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    var user = this;
    // hash password if it present and has changed
    if (user.password && user.isModified('password')) {
        // update password
    } else {
        return next();
    }
});
```

Using this approach, you may have to use either e.g.

```
var user = new User({ password: req.body.password });
user.save();
```

or

```
user.set({ password: req.body.password });
user.save();
```

Not sure if first example will work with the setter.